# fetch registered user posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am making a wordpress website on which the main posts are coming on the homepage .
I want that if a user regiters on the website and if he make posts  on the website , his/her post should go on a a specific page rather than coming on the homepage where the main admin posts are coming .
how to fetch the registered user posts to a specific page .
Please help if anyone can .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell me the role of user who will be registered? Will it be only subscriber or can be of any role?

Comment: Thanx for the reply Pranita .
The role of the user will be 'author' .

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the author ID. For *content-home.php* page use

```
$posts = get_posts('author=1&posts_per_page=1&orderby=date&order=desc');
$post = $posts[0];
```

If you want to show only the latest post.

And for the other page exclude this ID.

```
$posts = get_posts('author=-1');
```

Comment: Thanx for replying spaceman .
i have a file named 'content-home.php' from where the main post is coming on the home page .
In that file there is code  " <?php
global $post; ?> "
How do i exclude the author post from here or where should i place your code to exclude the posts of users .

Comment: Edited my answer. Try it.

Comment: $posts = get_posts('author=-1');
I have inserted this code into my content-home.php ,
only user post is coming on the home page by this .
but i want that , on the home page , only admin posts come and the user posts don't come , and the user post go on another specific page .
What to do ?

Comment: thanx spaceman , it worked ....but there is a problem ...
though the user post is not coming on the homepage but the 'readmore' button and its post meta details are coming there also after the main posts ...
see http://whatsappstatus.co/
here i have done only one post as a user and 3 posts as admin but after the admin posts , the 'readmore button' and post meta details of that user post are also coming . what should i do ?

Comment: @Hussain hard to say. I'm not sure I understand your problem 100%. Maybe you could show me the code of content-home.php page. Upload it somewhere.